# IOS: how to show API's content on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

in my app i am using a `UITextView` to display Text content on my view. I have an API for the text content to be display on `UITextView`.
but now i am confused how to display the API content on `UITextView`. Someone 
please provide me the complete code to implement.

API URL: http://any_url

i am sharing the details of the API
[image]

Comment: provide your API @Abhi

Comment: API URL: http://192.198.0.51/hpch/api/cms_page its a local api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-
**FOR GET REQUEST**

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&media=software"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    } else {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }
}];
```

**FOR POST REQUEST**

```
NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_API"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                         @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                         nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    } else {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

**In the mapData dictionary there will be your parameters if any. 
And if not Eliminate this code**

```
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                         @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                         nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

And then assigned the json to the text property of UITextView's object.

Comment: @Abhi This is the code. Is it a get api or a post api?

Comment: its a POST API which now runs on local server

Comment: @Abhi, Check the main Answer. I have updated the code.

Comment: it shows an exception"second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'"

Comment: @Abhi Show me your request

Comment: NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"data[Page][title]",
                             nil];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97186/discussion-between-abhi-and-arif-vadkey).

Answer (score 1):

Your data won't magically appear in your `UITextView`. You will have to do a network request with `NSURLSession` and parse the data, then you can implement the `UITextView` its properties and add the data.

Comment: the same thing i mention in my please provide me the code for how to do this